# How to dim the screen on an Android phone without locking?

Tags: lock-screens, battery, sleep, screen-timeout

Given a phone with a password, the screen turns off and the phone locks by single pressing the power button, or if the sleep time-out is reached.  The user then must enter the password to get access.

In order to conserve battery power, is is possible to have the screen dim but NOT lock the phone?

The user could increase the sleep setting so the screen would take longer to auto-dim, but that would not preserve the battery.

There are references to a "screen mode widget" that would dim the screen without locking, it does not appear to be available any longer.

Is there a trustworthy app that does this? By trustworthy I mean one that has an Internet presence other than their own page.

Comment: You don't need to post a new question to add a new answer.  It was a great answer though, so I've merged it over to the other question and upvoted it.